# How to use self and event in a class function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

No matter how I try it I keep getting the error that I need to send an argument to the event.

and yes before you say to go look at the documentation. I have looked at it but it doesn't help with what I'm doing because it is never inside a class.

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.callback()
        self.initUI()

        self.mainloop()

    def callback(self, event):
        print("made it")

    def initUI(self):

        canvas = Canvas(self, height = 300, width = 300)
        canvas.create_rectangle(1.5,1.5,40,40, tag = "obj1")
        canvas.tag_bind("obj1", '<Button-1>', callback) #where I assume the problem is happening

A = App()
```

EDIT: callback keeps saying it needs another argument but I don't know what it needs

Comment: Give us the smallest possible example program that illustrates your problem. As written, your question is too broad and unfocused and will likely be closed.

Comment: Please detail what you mean by "send an argument to event".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined your callback to take two arguments: `self` (meaning, it's a method on an object) and `event`. When you call it directly with `self.callback()`, `self` gets automatically passed, but you aren't passing in an event. That is why you get the error saying it needs another argument. It expects two, but is only getting one.

It's unclear what you are attempting to do by directly calling your callback, but a quick fix is to make the `event` attribute optional so you can call the callback directly or via a binding. Of course, this will only work if your binding doesn't actually use the `event` parameter. If it does, when calling it without an `event` you can expect it to fail.

Here's an example of making the `event` parameter optional:

```
def callback(self, event=None):
    print("made it")
```

That solves one problem, but you also have to change how your binding is defined or your code will crash when it starts up. You need to prepend `self` to the callback:

```
canvas.tag_bind("obj1", '<Button-1>', self.callback)
```

When callback is called, `self` again is automatically passed as the first argument. Tkinter will automatically add the `event` parameter.

Pedantically speaking, you should not be calling `mainloop()` inside of `__init__`. That prevents the `App` object from fully being constructed. The proper way to do it is to call `mainloop` outside of the constructor:

```
A = App()
A.mainloop()
```